# How do I remove the phone character auto-formatted into numbers? (Google docs is interpreting numbers as phone numbers when they are not

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to enter registration numbers into Google Docs. When I enter a number, a phone character is automatically added and formatting added to the numbers. I would like to just see plain text.

I enter: "#480704200(+)0" and it formats as "#4807042000" with blue text and underlining.

I need plain text. No phone icon. No formatting.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. As questions on this site should be specific I removed the mention of Google Sheets. You might post the a similar questions for Google Sheets. Also, please add more in order to help other to reproduce the problem (by the way, so far I was not able to reproduce it in Google Docs).

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after it changes to the phone formatting, either press the backspace key or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>.